# Prove function $f(\textbf{x})=\frac{(\textbf{y} \cdot \textbf{x})}{|\textbf{x}|}$ is continuous for all $\textbf{x}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Prove function $f(\textbf{x})=\frac{(\textbf{y} \cdot \textbf{x})}{|\textbf{x}|}$ is continuous for all $\textbf{x}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for some fixed $\textbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$

---

(I will denote the norm of a vector by $|\textbf{x}|$ as opposed to $||\textbf{x}||$)

My attempt is the following, however I later realized it is flawed as I assumed that $|\textbf{x}|$ and $|\textbf{x}_0|$ satisfy $1<|\textbf{x}_0||\textbf{x}|$ and $|\textbf{x}_0|,|\textbf{x}| \neq 0$ , so I would like some tips of how to get out of this situation. Here goes:

${\it\text{Proof}}$: Using the definition of continuity, we require that there exist some $\delta$ such that $0<|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0|<\delta$ implies
$$\left|\frac{(\textbf{y} \cdot \textbf{x})}{|\textbf{x}|} - \frac{(\textbf{y} \cdot \textbf{x}_0)}{|\textbf{x}_0|}\right|< \varepsilon$$
Using the faulty assumptions, we have
$$\left|\frac{(\textbf{y} \cdot \textbf{x})}{|\textbf{x}|} - \frac{(\textbf{y} \cdot \textbf{x}_0)}{|\textbf{x}_0|}\right|< ||\textbf{x}_0|(\textbf{x} \cdot \textbf{y})-|\textbf{x}|(\textbf{x}_0 \cdot \textbf{y})|$$

For $|\textbf{x}_0|\geq|\textbf{x}|$ we have that

$$
||\textbf{x}_0|(\textbf{x} \cdot \textbf{y})-|\textbf{x}|(\textbf{x}_0 \cdot \textbf{y})| < |\textbf{x}_0|(|(\textbf{x} \cdot \textbf{y})-(\textbf{x}_0 \cdot \textbf{y})|)< |\textbf{x}_0||\textbf{y}||\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0|\\
< |\textbf{x}_0||\textbf{y}||\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0|<\varepsilon.$$
Thus, we choose  $\delta = \min \left({ \frac{\varepsilon}{|\textbf{x}_0||\textbf{y}|},\frac{\varepsilon}{|\textbf{x}||\textbf{y}|} }\right)$.

As stated, this proof is built on a handful of assumptions, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You speak of $x_0$, but $x_0$ doesn't appear in $f$. Can you update your question to explain this? Also what difference do you make between the magnitude of $x$ and its norm?

Comment: There are issues around $x_0=0$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I used only the norm of a vector through out the proof, no absolute values. And about $x_0$, that is just some arbitrary point in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we evaluate $f$ at $x_0$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Yeah, however nothing is stated about this. The initial problem is stated fully in first paragraph of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_1(x)=(y,x),f_2(x)=|x|^{-1}$ are both continuous in $\mathbb R^n\backslash\{0\}$ then the function $f=f_1f_2$ is continuous (in general)   in $\mathbb R^n\backslash\{0\}$, but itsn't continuous in $x=0$ because:
$$\lim_{t\to 0}f(ty^{\perp})=0  ,$$
$$\lim_{t\to 0}f(ty)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(y,ty)}{t|y|}=\frac{(y,y)}{|y|}=|y| $$...so the function is continuous iff $y=0$.